# Error: Can't resolve 'dns' during npm run build in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dns, package.json, npm-build

I'm getting the following error with dns during `npm run build` in Dockerfile.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/reactProj/node_modules/ioredis/built/cluster'
```

dns is configured in the package.json to point to a mock file.

```
    "dns": "file:./lib/__mocks__/dns",
```

What change should I be doing for this?

Dockerfile for ref:

```
FROM node:16
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /reactProj
COPY ./package.json /reactProj
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This got fixed by removing the following from Dockerfile

```
NODE_ENV production
```

`npm run build` command from scripts already sets the same.